# What are the equations for calculating armor values on the character sheet and armory profile?

Tags: diablo-iii

The main purpose of this question is to be able to enter a series of armor values for gear, and then calculate a value that exactly matches the character paper-doll screen *and* the armory value for any given character.

The answer must take into account character level, bonuses from gear, enchantress buffs, and strength.  For the armory value, what buffs apply? I believe if Warcry is spec'd, then on the armory page, it does factor into the shown value.

Currently, the equation I'm using is: `Armor Value = Armor Values on Gear + Strength` However, this is calculated value 39 armor lower than the in-game value.  The disparity is even greater when viewing my character profile, which has Warcry spec'd, even accounting for 20% increase in armor.

Comment: Are you taking paragon level into account? I know that would be reflected in the strength score in-game, but I think you need to specifically include it when using the armory API.

Comment: all active buffs that are on your character, when you exit a game, will reflect on armory values, this include any active or passive skills, enchantress buffs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

yx, yes, I am accounting for the 20% buff from Warcry (as stated in the post). I also do not have any armor reducing passives.

@dpatchery, I am indeed counting my paragon levels when calculating strength.  I am not using levels at all to calculate the base value, just the armor from my gear.  I assumed levels do not *directly* increase armor as the 39 disparity is much less than my l60 base and l60 paragon.

Comment: http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?835206-How-things-are-calculated-in-Diablo-3

This lists the equation as: `FLOOR((Armor + Armor Item Total + Strength Total) * (Armor Bonus Percent + 1))`

FLOOR is a function that merely rounds values down to the nearest integer.  With No bonus armor, this equation is still coming up short...